# how do I disable the "view all products" in magento 1.8

Tags: magento

In the admin, under catalog, there is  "Allow All Products per Page".

Whether to show "All" option in the "Show X Per Page" dropdown."  It is marked "NO"  However on live site,  each and every products page has the option "View All" at the bottom.

We have at least 4 -5 big categories, When you go into: http://addalinkofcharm.com/italian-charm-categories.html  And you select All at the bottom of the page, you get this url:

http://addalinkofcharm.com/italian-charm-categories.html?limit=all

This is a SEO nightmare! On this page by doing the all, provides  2791 products If the view all was disabled even if I could just have no more than 100 links per page would help.  I do not know how else to do this unless I do away with the Italian Charm Category page and just keep the individual categories.

Even in some of the sub categories we have big categories like the Miscellaneous, Or Flags, etc and these show more than 100 links if someone views "ALL".

These 2 suggestions were in the magento forum:

> 1. app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List
>
> /YOURMAGENTO/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/toolbar.php
>
> Lines 539 and 598 (list view; then grid view)

Change:

> return ($perPageValues + array(’all’=>$this->__(’All’)));

to:

> return ($perPageValues);
>
> 1. app/code/core/catalog/block/product/list/toolbar.php

Looks for lines 255 & 264, should look like this:

> return ($perPageValues + array(’all’=>$this->__(’All’)));

Change them to:

> return ($perPageValues);

I need to know how to change the amount of products on pages can you help?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can disable "All" option from magento admin itself.

find the below steps

```
1.Login to magento admin
2.Go to System->Configuration->Catalog (Left hand side)
3.Click on catalog (under Catalog option)->select "Frontend" option
4.In Allow All Products per Page set to "No".
```

Comment: It is selected "NO", However it is NOT responding, the live site still has it as an option.  Tracy

Answer (score 0):

Please check the http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-change-default-amount-of-products-in-products-listing.html

you can set here number of products per page. Hope this help you